# Flutter isSBSettingEnabled

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-test

Samsung Android 9 is throwing `isSBSettingEnabled false` then not sending a multipart request. I have created a custom network security config, enabled HTTP legacy in android manifest, and tried allowing clear traffic. I have even tried using an HTTP Client lib such as Dio.

I get a successful http GET request, however when attempting to send a MultiPartRequest the `isSBSettingEnabled false` shows and the POST request is never sent. There is no error being logged.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you :)